# How to find the following density function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is distributed exponentially with parameter $\lambda$.

Define $Y=X^2$.

How would I find out $f_Y(t)$ the density function of $Y$.

Any help?

Comment: Find the cdf of $X^2$ (i.e. $\Pr(X^2\le y)$), and then differentiate.

Comment: How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

$F_Y(y) = P\{Y \leq y\} = P\{X^2\leq y\} = P\{-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}\} = F_X(\sqrt{y})- F_X(-\sqrt{y})$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Actually yes I think I can let me try and I will post results.

Comment: Would it be $1-e^{-\lambda \sqrt {t}}$ for $t>0$ and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: @Ben: are you sure this is the PDF of $Y = X^2$? (Remember, integral over $f_Y(y)$ should be equal to $1$.)

Comment: @Amin Well I used the fact that $F_X(-\sqrt{y})=0$ since the exponential distribution is non-negative and then $F_X(\sqrt{y})=\int_0^{\sqrt y} \lambda e^{-\lambda x}~dx$ to get my result using the formula given by Dilip above. Did I make an algebra slip somewhere or am I just wrong?

Comment: @Amin Conventiionally, $F_X$ denotes the cumulative probability _distribution_ function and $f_X$ denies the probability _density_ function as you yourself have used in your own answer. Ben's answer is correct (for the CDF). Differentiating it gives the pdf which is the same that you found using your magical mystical formula.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I thought that he want the PDF not CDF. Then, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here $X$ is an exponential distribution random variable with parameter $\lambda$,

$$f_X (x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, $$

Then by change of variable, we have:

$$Y = g(X) = X^2$$
$$x = g^{-1}(y) = y^{\frac{1}{2}},$$

$$ \frac{d[g^{-1}(y)]}{dy} = \frac{1}{2} y^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

and by formula (from change of variable technique):

$$f_Y (y) = f_X (g^{-1}(y)) |\frac{d[g^{-1}(y)]}{dy}|,$$

$$ \implies f_Y (y) =\lambda e^{-\lambda y^{\frac{1}{2}}} \frac{1}{2} y^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{\lambda}{{2} {\sqrt{y}}} e^{-\lambda \sqrt{y}}.$$

*Alternative approach:*

The cumulative distribution function (CDF) is

$$F_Y(y) = P\{Y=X^2 \leq y\} = P\{-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y}\} = F_X(\sqrt{y}) \\ = \int_{0}^{\sqrt{y}} f_X(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\sqrt{y}} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx = 1 - e^{- \lambda \sqrt{y}},$$

then for probability density function (PDF) from the derivative of $F_Y(y)$ w.r.t $y$ we have 
$$\implies f_Y(y) = \frac{d[F_Y(y)]}{dy} = \frac{\lambda}{{2} {\sqrt{y}}} e^{-\lambda \sqrt{y}}.$$

---

Note: Change of variable technique

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with probability density function $f_X(x)$ over an interval $S$. Suppose the mapping $Y = g(X)$ where $g: S \rightarrow T$ is a differentiable function.

- If $g$ is a strictly increasing function:

  $$F_Y (y) = \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(g(X) \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq g^{-1}(y)) = F_X [g^{-1}(y)]$$
  such that $y \in T$. Then, by taking derivatives w.r.t $y$ we have

  $$f_Y(y) = \frac{d[F_Y(y)]}{dy} = f_X{(g^{-1}(y))}\frac{d[g^{-1}(y)]}{dy} $$
- If $g$ is a strictly decreasing function:

  $$F_Y (y) = \mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(g(X) \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X \geq g^{-1}(y)) = 1 - F_X [g^{-1}(y)]$$
  such that $y \in T$. Then, by taking derivatives w.r.t $y$ we have

  $$f_Y(y) = \frac{d[F_Y(y)]}{dy} = -f_X{(g^{-1}(y))}\frac{d[g^{-1}(y)]}{dy}.$$

Comment: @BenB: I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the more general case: Let $Y = g(X)$ and let 
$$f_X(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathbb{P}(X < x)$$
assuming it exists. 
Then,
$$\mathbb{P}(Y  < y) = \mathbb{P}( g(X)  < y) = \mathbb{P}( X \in g^{-1}((-\infty,y)) )$$

Now let $ g^{-1}((-\infty,y)) = (a_1,b_1) \cup(a_2,b_2) \cup (a_3,b_3) \cup \ldots  $, where $a_1<b_1<a_2<b_2<a_3<b_3<\ldots$
Then,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}( Y < y)
&= \mathbb{P}( X \in (a_1,b_1) ) + \mathbb{P}( X \in (a_1,b_2) ) +\mathbb{P}( X \in (a_3,b_3) ) + \ldots\\
&= \mathbb{P}( X < b_1) - \mathbb{P}( X < a_1) 
+\mathbb{P}( X < b_2) - \mathbb{P}( X < a_2)
+\mathbb{P}( X < b_3) - \mathbb{P}( X < a_3)+ \ldots\\
\Rightarrow 
f_Y(y) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\mathbb{P}(Y< y)
 &= \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}b_1}{\mathrm{d}y}\right) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}b_1} \mathbb{P}( X < b_1)-\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}a_1}{\mathrm{d}y}\right) \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a_1} \mathbb{P}( X < a_1)  + \ldots\\
&= \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}b_1}{\mathrm{d}y}\right) f_X(b_1)-\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}a_1}{\mathrm{d}y}\right) f_X(a_1)  + \ldots
\end{align}
In your case, $f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\mathbb{1}_{x > 0}$, and $g(x) = x^2 \Rightarrow g^{-1}((-\infty, y)) = (-\sqrt{y},\sqrt{y})$. So 
$$f_Y(y)= \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\sqrt{y}}{\mathrm{d}y}\right) \lambda e^{-\lambda \sqrt{y}}\mathbb{1}_{\sqrt{y} >0}-\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}(-\sqrt{y})}{\mathrm{d}y}\right) \lambda e^{\lambda\sqrt{y}}\mathbb{1}_{-\sqrt{y} >0} = \frac{\lambda}{2\sqrt{y}} e^{-\lambda \sqrt{y}}$$

Comment: Re the mention "In the more general case", one may note that the assumption that $ g^{-1}((-\infty,y))$ is, for every $y$, a (countable at most?) disjoint union of open intervals is a restriction on the functions $g$ one can treat this way.