# Random variable transformations and rates of change.

Tags: random-variables, transformation

X is a uniform random variable on (0,1) and $Y=\sqrt{X}$. We can find $F_Y(y)$ and $f_Y(y)$

$
  F_Y(y) =
  \begin{cases}
   1 & \text{if $1 \leq x$} \\
   y^2 & \text{if $0<x<1$} \\
   0 & \text{if $x \leq 0$}
  \end{cases}
$

and so

$
  f_Y(y) =
  \begin{cases}
   2y & \text{if $0<x<1$} \\
   0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$

I would like to know if there is a relationship between the fact that $Y=g(x)=\sqrt{X}$ is increasing at a decreasing rate and the nature of $F_Y(y)$ and $f_Y(y)$. That is $g(.4)-g(.2) > g(.6)-g(.4) > g(.8)-g(.6)$ even though all of the intervals are the same size for x.

I heard something in a lecture years ago about this and it made sense at the time, but looking at my notes I can't figure out why I wrote "$f_Y(y)=2y$ since $Y=g(x)=\sqrt{X}$ becomes more dense as X increases"

I was really impressed with this since it has like 5 stars next to it.

Any help would be gratefully received. Googling things like "density of random variables transformation" has not been effective.

Naturally this is a general principle I'm looking for that applies to any case where g(x) increases at a decreasing rate.

Comment: This might be helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2235981/175036 .